# Visualising relation between dependent and independent variables

Tags: python, plot, jupyter, visualization

While doing Exploratory Data analysis of dataset with this code below on Jupyter, I am getting output processed of the plot but unable to see the plot. I am using Google `Colab`. What could be the reason?

```
def tar_var_summary(df, tar_var):
    colors = ['#a2b9bc', '#6b5b95', '#b2ad7f', '#feb236', '#b5e7a0', '#878f99',
              '#d64161', '#86af49', '#ff7b25']
    
    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                        subplot_titles=('Countplot', 'Percentages'),
                        specs=[[{"type": "xy"}, {'type': 'domain'}]])
    
    x = [str(i) for i in df[tar_var].value_counts().index]
    y = df[tar_var].value_counts().values.tolist()
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = x, y = y, text = y, 
                         textposition = "auto",
                       showlegend = False,
                        marker=dict(color=colors,
                              line = dict(color = 'black',
                                          width = 2))), row=1, col=1)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels = df[tar_var].value_counts().keys(),
                         values = df[tar_var].value_counts().values,
                         pull = [0, 0.25],
                         hoverinfo ='label',
                  textinfo ='percent',
                  textfont_size = 20,
                  textposition ='auto',
                  marker=dict(colors=colors,
                              line = dict(color = 'black',
                                          width = 2))), row=1, col=2)

    
    fig.update_layout(title={'text': "Distribution of the Target Variable",
                         'y':0.9,
                         'x':0.5,
                         'xanchor': 'center',
                         'yanchor': 'top'},
                  template='plotly_dark')
    
    iplot(fig)

tar_var_summary(df, "mpg")
```

I was trying to visualise relationship among variables. I could not get the plot though.